# iOS Mask Image size too high

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, mask

I wasn't sure how to name this, sorry for the title.

I have an image that I want to fill more or less depending on a variable. For this, I created an image made of black and white (below). The goal is to use it as a mask and fill it the way I want, based on this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html).

[image: Mask]

The issue: the image is drawn properly BUT its dimensions are way too high. I test it on iPhone 6+ with a @3x image, the image asset size is correct but the image that is returned by my function is way too big. When I put constraints on my UIImageView*, I only view part of the returned filled image; when I don't, the image is way too big. See below for a screenshot (iPhone 6+)

[image: Simulator]

I subclassed a UIView with the following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
NSLog(@"%0.f", width);
CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height;
NSLog(@"%0.f", height);
CGFloat fillHeight = 0.9 * height;
NSLog(@"%0.f", fillHeight);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


CGRect fillRect = CGRectMake(0, height - fillHeight, width, fillHeight);
CGContextAddRect(context, fillRect);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, fillRect);

CGRect emptyRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height - fillHeight);
CGContextAddRect(context, emptyRect);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, emptyRect);
}

- (UIImage *)renderAsImage
{
// setup context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0); // use same scale factor as device
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// render view
[self.layer renderInContext:c];

// get reslting image
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSLog(@"result size = %d width, %d height", result.size.width, result.size.height);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return result;
}
```

And in my ViewController:

```
- (void) setUpMaskedImage
    {
    // Image View set in Storyboard that will contain the final image. Bounds are set in Storyboard (constraints)
UIImageView* imageView = self.containingImageView;

// Custom View (see methods above) that will draw a rectangle filled with color
UIView* view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame: imageView.frame];

// Mask Image used along with the custom view to create final view (see image above)
UIImage* maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"maskImage"];

[view setNeedsDisplay];
UIImage* fillImage = [view renderAsImage];

CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
UIImage* imageToDisplay = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
[imageView setImage:imageToDisplay];
}
```

I just don't get it. I used similar code elsewhere in my app and it works just fine. I will do a sample project soon if necessary.

Thank you!

Comment: I got a similar problem. In one view, there was Autolayout enabled in the Storyboard. Apple change this from default false to default true, so samples for XCode 5 still work in XCode 6m but it will not work in new added views.

Comment: Are you saying the issue is related to versions of XCode? I have 6.1, Auto Layout enabled so I don't understand why it would be the cause...

Comment: Honestly, I did not look into your code maybe the error is there, that is the reason I posted this as comment, not as answer. The worse thing is, that samples generated with XCode 5 still works in XCode 6. The default layout value is applied only to new Storyboard elements. If you change size or position of a view with autolayout on - at least in my project - the results are unpredictical.  Turn autolayout of for a test.